# why StringTokenizer does not work properly for $$ as delimeter

Tags: java, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I am using `StringTokenizer` to tokenize a string with `$$` as delimeter but if my string is  like `$1$dga74` then it tokenize this from first `$`. Can any body tell me why this happens and what can I do to remove this issue.

```
String str="/getCPage.asp?m=total&sub=$1$dga74$$/getEpage.asp?m=tatal&sub=0";
StringTokenizer tok=new StringTokenizer(str,"$$")
String url1=tok.nextToken();
String url2=tok.nextToken();
```

Comment: I believe it works with single char tokens only.`The characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens.` from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: You should use split instead

Comment: `String[] splited = str.split("$$");` should do what you need

Comment: @karthik, but split take the tokenizer as regular expression which may also cause issue as my string allows special characters and the are not static they are dynamic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each character in the `delim` argument is treated as a delimiter character. If you specify `"$$"` you specify `$` twice (the second is ignored).

To solve your problem you can use a `Scanner`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "/getCPage.asp?m=total&sub=$1$dga74$$/getEpage.asp?m=tatal&sub=0";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\$\\$");

    System.out.println(scanner.next());
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Outputs:

```
/getCPage.asp?m=total&sub=$1$dga74
/getEpage.asp?m=tatal&sub=0
```

Comment: *Note: that I suggested `Scanner` since it has the same kind of functionality as the `StringTokenizer` you are used to.*

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer works with single character tokens only.

You can use the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a simple loop to achieve the results that you are looking for:

```
List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([$]{1,2}|=>?| +)");
String s = "$1$dga74$$";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int pos = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    if (pos != m.start()) {
        res.add(s.substring(pos, m.start()));
    }
    res.add(m.group());
    pos = m.end();
}
if (pos != s.length()) {
    res.add(s.substring(pos));
}
for (String t : res) {
    System.out.println("'"+t+"'");
}
```